# cp copying more than what is asked

Tags: linux, command-line, filenames, file-transfer

I go with the following in bash

```
cp -r "/wordpress/3.0.1/" "/mySite/"
```

and the result is `/mySite/3.0.1/` but I don't want nor understand why the `3.0.1/` appears in the target destination.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cp -r /wordpress/3.0.1/* /mySite

Comment: That won't copy any file in `/wordpress/3.0.1/` whose name begins with a `.`. Better use `cp -r /wordpress/3.0.1/. /mySite/`.

Comment: @Gilles I'll give it a try, tx

Answer (score 3):

This is a deviation from the [POSIX specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11), which states that

> A pathname that contains at least one non-slash character and that ends with one or more trailing slashes shall be resolved as if a single dot character ( '.' ) were appended to the pathname.

But under Linux (i.e. with the `cp` command from [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), `cp -r foo/ bar/` acts like `cp -r foo bar/` rather than `cp -r foo/. bar/` when `foo` is a directory¹. (GNU coreutils isn't the only culprit, I just observed the same behavior in OpenBSD which is usually good at standards compliance.)

You can run `cp -r "/wordpress/3.0.1/." "/mySite/"` (i.e. end the source with `/.`) to avoid the `3.0.1/` level. Another possibility is `rsync -r "/wordpress/3.0.1/" "/mySite/"`.

As an aside, I recommend getting into the habit of `cp -a` rather than `cp -r` if you don't use unices other than Linux and Cygwin. When you notice the difference, `-a` (which preserves permissions and symbolic links) is usually the right one. On other unices, use `cp -Rp`. With `rsync`, use `-a`.

Comment: Thanks! Is the use of double quotes to capture the path important?

Comment: @fabjoa: Here the double quotes are not necessary. You will often find them in (well-written) scripts, because they are necessary around variable substitutions (e.g. `cp -- "$1" "$destination"`). When the file name is specified directly, quotes are necessary only if the name contains characters that are special to the shell, such as spaces; single quotes (apostrophes) `'foo'` would be more common because they protect everything except single quotes. (Shell quoting rules are complicated.)

Comment: @Gilles I'm confused by "`cp -r foo/ bar/` acts like `cp -r foo bar/` rather than `cp -r foo bar/`" - I'd expect that the last two should be different?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I meant “rather than `cp -r foo/. bar/`”. Fixed, thanks.